# dynamic id generating when appending a row and calling time difference function in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Am using trent's timepicker addon for generating timepicker in a tabular format. with start time and end time in same row along based on which time difference is calculated.for generating multiple timepicker i used class instead of id. trouble is i would like to generate dynamic id and append a row with calculate() in it .

Below is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //table grid structure follows here
    $("#AddRow").click(function() {
        var row = '<tr><td>' +'<input type=text /></td>' + '<td><input type=text class="timepicker" value=""/></td>' + '<td><input type=text class="timepicker" value=""/></td>' + '<td><input type=text id= "difference" /></td>' + '<td><button>delete</button>' + '</td></tr>';
        $("#table").append(row);

    });
    $('body').on('focus', ".timepicker", function() {
        $(this).timepicker({});
    });

    $("#table").on("click", "button", function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
    //table structure ends here
});
```

Any ways to achieve it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sessionStorage" is not supported by IE browsers...
Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=0;
$('input.timepicker').each(function(){
    i++;
    $(this).attr("id","timepicker_"+i);
});
```

});

Comment: the "sessionStorage" is not supported by IE browsers older than IE 8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: this worked thanks :).. but if am suppose to calculate time difference based on these dynamic id how am suppose do ? here is the code that i would like to implement on this : `"$("input.timepicker").keyup(function(b) { `
 `$("#difference").val(tdiff($("#timepicker_"+i).val(),` `$("#timepicker_"+i).val()));" `..... should i implment the code like this  ?

Comment: You can get the current element id using "$(this).id" in side the "keyup" function... What are the elements or ids you need to find the tdiff? If it is adjascent elements, you can just add "1" or "substact "1" from the current id...

Comment: the id's that i need for tdiff is the starttime id and endtime  id, in this case, the first row is displaying starttime as #timepicker_1 and endtime as #timepicker_2 like wise in the second row #timepicker_3 etc at the run time ...

Comment: `function mdiff(t1,t2) { 
    var t1 = hour2mins(t1);  var t2=hour2mins(t2); 
    var ret = mins2hour(parseInt(t2-t1));
  if(t2<t1) {
     ret=mins2hour(parseInt(parseInt(t2+1440)-t1));
  } 
    return ret; 
}`

`$("input.diff").keyup(function (b){ 
   $("#duration").val(mdiff($("#starttime).val(),$("#endtime").val())); //all the three id should take dynamic id's too
});`
 can you tell how am suppose to do this in this code **[fiddle]**(http://jsfiddle.net/manmohan_menon/2D4nZ/6/)

Comment: You need to update these lines...1)<td><input type=text id="diff"/></td> to <td><input type=text id="diff" class="timepicker"/></td> in HTML, 2) <td><input type=text id class="diff"/></td> to <td><input type=text id class="diff timepicker"/></td> in $("#AddRow").click

Answer (score 0):

an idea for generating dynamic Ids would be to store a numeric value in the session storage, value that you would concatenate to a constant prefix. The numeric value will be incremented after it was used. Something like:

```
var id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
if (!id) {
    id = 0;
}
var idValue = "myId" + id.toString();
sessionStorage.setItem("id", id++);
```